# Live Stream deletion difficulties

Tags: facebook, stream, live

I'm currently using the live stream app for my website but I can't delete posts that I make on the live steam itself, if I post it to Facebook I can access it on Facebook and delete it there but with comments that I post only on the live stream I can't delete them.

Is there a way to delete posts or even reset the app without changing the XID?

Answer (score 1):

It is to be noted that only 6 posts can be displayed at a time. So if you want to delete a post just override with a new one but make sure there should be 6 posts... Dont forget to refresh the page.